# Cmake FetchContent googletest not working on windows

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

Using `FetchContent()` to integrate gtest into project in cmake seems to be missing the relevant include path for `gtest/gtest.h`

Building on linux works fine with gcc

```
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

But building on windows with msvc

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall" x86
cmake -G "Ninja" ..
cmake --build .
```

**Results in:**

`Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory`

`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/internal/gtest-port.h`

**Main cmake:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(VERBOSE ON)

project(test)

option(UNIT_TESTS "Build the unit tests" ON)
if(UNIT_TESTS)
  enable_testing()
  add_subdirectory(test)
endif()
```

**Here is relevant test cmake:**

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(gtest
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
  GIT_TAG release-1.11.0)

  set(gtest_force_shared_crt ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gtest)

set(project "test_example")
add_executable(${project} example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${project} gtest_main)

include(GoogleTest)
gtest_discover_tests(${project})
```

**Update**

Just tested on windows using clang compiler and  it works, so seems specific to msvc.

Comment: Which **source file** is compiled when you faced that error message? Is it source file for your test or is it belongs to googletest itself?

Comment: the latter (e.g. `FAILED: _deps/gtest-build/googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/__/googletest/src/gtest-all.cc.obj`)

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly changing `FetchContent_Declare(gtest` to `FetchContent_Declare(googletest` fixed this issue. I found this page https://github.com/google/googletest/issues/2457 which seems to be exact same issue as I had.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue as well. I'm surprised more people haven't run into it.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Which is unfortunate, because I want to use the new feature `OVERRIDE_FIND_PACKAGE`, which should use the same name as the find-module (-> gtest)